# fields that don't pass validations don't get .field_with_errors class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My validations work fine

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :car_number, :name, :phone, presence:true
validates_uniqueness_of :car_number 
has_many :cars
has_many :visits
accepts_nested_attributes_for :visits
```

and my save.js.erb

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if  @owner.errors.any? %>
<% @owner.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
$("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
$('.field_with_errors').addClass('has-error has-feedback');

<% end
else %>

$("#new_owner_div").html("<%= j (render 'visits/show', { :f => @visit })%>")
<%end%>
```

but no fields get under class 'field_with_errors'.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: have you inspected your view after validation failure for `field_with_errors` class & is errors loop in js is executing for sure ?

Comment: Yes Muhammad, I did' the loop with no <%end%> was only here, pasted that incorrectly, the errors are being shown in a div.

toddmetheny: I am trying to mark fields with errors in a class of their own, I've read this is done automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as always, troubles that takes much time to resolve are easier than I thought.

I found how to for each error's input by this [ assuming your inputs are named: modelname[field_name]

```
 <% @owner.errors.each do |attribute, error| %>
$('[name="owner[<%=attribute%>]"]').addClass('field_with_errors')
<% end %>
```

where in css:

```
.field_with_errors {
             border: 2px solid red
                }
```